# how to connect UI items within Storyboard to Swift variables

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

*Disclaimer: Learning iOS Dev with Swift - so Noob here*

Trying to drop UI Items from Storyboard to Swift file, [here's what I am doing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6eoxIm6MiM&feature=youtu.be).

What am I doing wrong? how can i import handles to the UI elements in Swift file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl + Mouse (Left Click) drag and drop

OR

Mouse (Right Click) drag and drop

Answer (score 0):

I had to hold down the <kbd>control</kbd> key and then drag the UI element.